# Get the percentage of the unique elements in a column using table() in R

Tags: r

So I have this column of data in excel named level about 1k long

| Level |
| --- |
| Low |
| Medium |
| High |
| High |
| High |
| High |
| Low |
| Low |
| Medium |
| Medium |
| High |
| High |

....

and I want to get the number of each low, medium and high occurance and also the percentage of each in the column.

I tried getting the numbers of each occurance with the code below

```
#percentage of level
table(data$Level)
```

below is the output

```
High    Low Medium 
   365    303    332
```

but to get the percentage is quite tricky for me since I'm new to R. Also I want to sort them so that it displays as Low Medium High. any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: You can do `prop.table(table(data$level))`

Comment: CAn you please elaborate more clearly? thanks

Comment: When you use `table` function on a vector, it will return the count of each unique level, this seems to be what you have done. When you use `prop.table()` on a vector (here on your count table), it outputs the proportion of each value of your vector. This will result in the proportion of each unique level of your variable.

Comment: Oh yes that's accurate my only challenge is getting the percentage of each count.

Comment: How do you want to sort them, by level name or by count, ascending or descending?

Comment: sort by name and get the percentage of each occurrence

Comment: Launch this `data$Level <- factor(data$Level, levels=c("Low", "Mid", "High"))` to order your labels as you want then launch the `prop.table(table(data$Level))`